# Difference between code1 and code2

Tags: c, mbedtls

code 1

```
uint8_t  ucAESKey_BASE64[] = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64;
pucAESKey_BASE64 = ucAESKey_BASE64;
```

code 2

```
uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
```

I use **mbedtls_base64_decode()** to decode base64 string ,the API of mbedTLS.

```
int mbedtls_base64_decode( unsigned char *dst, size_t dlen, size_t *olen,
                   const unsigned char *src, size_t slen )
```

My program like this：

```
mbedtls_base64_decode(ucAESKey, sizeof(ucAESKey), &olen, 
                      pucAESKey_BASE64, strlen(pucAESKey_BASE64));
```

If the parameter ***src** use code 2 , the output is

> 00 00 00 83 46 b4 56 b8 e2 55 4e fa 33 55 91 57

if *src use code 1, the output is

> a0 5a 93 83 46 b4 56 b8 e2 55 4e fa 33 55 91 57

and this is correct.
Why?

Comment: Why are you using `strlen` on a buffer that is not `const char *`?

Comment: Probably having problems because you are declaring one as an array and the other as not:

    uint8_t  ucAESKey_BASE64[] = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
    uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";

Should be:

    uint8_t  ucAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
    uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";

Comment: Show the declarations and how `ucAESKey` and `olen` are initialized.

Comment: can you try with this: `char *pcaAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";`

Comment: Usually it's the issue of [using `sizeof` with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492384/69809), expecting it to return the same as `strlen`. Is `ucAESKey` initialized the same way in both cases?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the exact thing you describe happens in reality. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since the input of `mbedtls_base64_decode()` is a base64 string, it is ok to use strlen, as we don't expect any null character within the input. 
I have tried reproducing your issue, but both inputs generate the same output, so I assume your other inputs are different, as @n.m. suggests.
I have tried the following:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned char ucAESKey[32] = { 0 };
    size_t olen = 32;
    size_t i;
#if 0
    uint8_t  ucAESKey_BASE64[] = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
    uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64;
    pucAESKey_BASE64 = ucAESKey_BASE64;
#else
    uint8_t *pucAESKey_BASE64 = "oFqTg0a0VrjiVU76M1WRVw==";
#endif
    mbedtls_base64_decode(ucAESKey, sizeof(ucAESKey), &olen,
                   pucAESKey_BASE64, strlen(pucAESKey_BASE64));

    for (i = 0; i < olen; i++)
    {
        mbedtls_printf("0x%x ", ucAESKey[i]); 
    }
return 0;
}
```